# Shuffling variables between a vector and the variable's original alignement

Tags: java, operating-system, jvm, virtual-machine

in the following paragraph:
"The instruction set requires that loads and stores from local memory are 128bit aligned. The registers are 128 bits wide, with instructions treating these 128 bits as a vector of sixteen 8-bit, eight 16-bit, four 32-bit or two 64-bit values, depending upon the operation.  Therefore, stack push and pop operations must shuffle variables between the first vector slot of a register and the variable’s original alignment"
Can someone please explain to me what shuffling variables means ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions doesn't appear to be about Java, but how the SSE2 registers work?

The SSE2 instruction set uses 128-bit registers, however most of the registers in a x86/x64 are 32-bit or 64-bit.  In any case Java hides these details from you and you don't need to know what the native register size of a system is.

Can you give some context to what you are talking about? Google could not find this quote you have provided.

If you are talking about SSE2, then shuffling means that the CPU can pack multiple smaller values into one large value by shifting by 8 each time for 8 bit values, 16 each time for 16 bit values etc. It does this so it can operate on all the values at once with a single operation.  Like a mini fixed size vector.  Longer vectors can be operated on by performing these operations many times.

Comment: The question is more about jvm implementation. The quote is from an article about a JVM called Hera-JVM which is implemented over the heterogeneous multi-core Cell processor (used in Playstation 3). The quote is about implementing a JVM on the SPE cores (Synergistic Processing Engine) but your answer still clarifies the meaning of "shuffling variables". Thanks